# Codeigniter - controller and method

Tags: codeigniter, controller

i'm developing a new site and i have this situation:

```
- Products
 \_ Category1
    \_Product1
    \_Product2
 \_ Category2
    \_Produc1
    \_Product2
```

I have created my Product controller to show all the category but now i need to create a controller for each category, is it possibile?
I would have something like:

www.example.com/product/category/product-name

how can i setup my controller? i can't write a method for each category because this is not definited...

Comment: are you using a database to store the category and products?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Product Controller, add a function load_category($category_name='') and route URL segment to this function.

Edit app/config/routes.php and add a line like this:

```
$route['product'] = 'product/index';
$route['product/(:any)'] = 'product/load_category/$1';
```

An so any URL like:
www.example.com/product/categorya or
www.example.com/product/categoryb or ..
will send a request to load_category methos from Product Controller.

Add this for products:

```
$route['product/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'product/load_product/$2';
```